# Best practices to run stats test and build ggplot charts on wide data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I'm working on a research project where the data frame has rows for subjects and columns for variables. The variables are divided into two major groups:

1. General characterization of the subject (ex. age, smoking, diagnosis) with a single measurement at the start of the study;
2. Pre and post-treatment variables of the same subjects on two independent columns. There's no control group at this point.

As my first endeavor in data science, I'm trying to build charts with stats test annotations using R instead of SPSS or Prism. However, based on the available coding literature and searches, the wide data frame format is not ideal for ggplot.

What's the best practice to convert it to the tall format in this case? I've seen others recommending melt(), but I'm unsure how I should factor the two major groups variables into a tall format.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What you've described *isn't* a wide dataset for most purposes. But consult the [tidy data vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) which explains the terminology, and also describes how to transform the data as needed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use pivot_longer() from the tidyr package.
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html